# How to display alert function from xamarin android button in webview

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

- How to display alert function from xamarin android button in webview
- I want to add an alert in webview when the user clicks on the Xamarin android button.

Comment: Hey we need something that you tried before we can help you

Comment: you mean call javascript function to show alert for webview?

Comment: I have try this but not work =>webView.EvaluateJavascript("javascript: alert('Hi');", null);

Comment: Have you enabled javascript for the webview with `webSettings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;`

Comment: I have done that all but not work.

Comment: WebSettings websettings = _webView.Settings;
            websettings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
            websettings.LoadWithOverviewMode = true;
            websettings.UseWideViewPort = true;
            websettings.AllowFileAccess = true;
            websettings.AllowContentAccess = true;
            websettings.AllowFileAccessFromFileURLs = true;
            websettings.AllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs = true;
            websettings.DomStorageEnabled = true;
            websettings.JavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true;

Comment: Do an API level check and then implement like in the following link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30256747/issue-with-webview-evaluatejavascript-in-android-xamarin

Comment: I have tried this already but not work.

Comment: Where is the code embedded?In ```OnCreate()```?. I figure its in a button click event handler?

Comment: Tried with both OnCreate and button click but not showing aleart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have try this but not work =>webView.EvaluateJavascript("javascript: alert('Hi');", null);

You can try to use WebChromeClient() by `webview1.SetWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());`

```
  protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
      
        webview1 = FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.webView1);
        button1 = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button1);

        button1.Click += Button1_Click;

        WebSettings settings = webview1.Settings;
        settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
        
        webview1.SetWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());        
        webview1.LoadUrl("file:///android_asset/login.html");
   
    }

    private void Button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        //webview1.EvaluateJavascript("javascript: check();", new EvaluateBack());
        webview1.EvaluateJavascript("javascript: alert('Hi');", null);
    }
```

The screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[image]
Implement webviewclient object for your webview and call `webview.EvaluateJavascript` in `OnPageFinished` like this..

```
//create an internal webviewclient class
 internal class webViewClient : WebViewClient
    {
        public override void OnPageStarted(WebView view, string url, Bitmap favicon)
        {
            base.OnPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }

        public override void OnPageFinished(WebView view, string url)
        {
            base.OnPageFinished(view, url);
              //define the javascript code you wish to run
            string script = "javascript:alert('Hi');";
            //perform check and then call
            if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.Kitkat)
            {
                view.EvaluateJavascript(script, null);
            }
            else
            {
                view.LoadUrl(script);
            }
        }
    }
```

and then in your `webview` code in either `OnCreate` or in `buttonclick evet handler` do this

```
 protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.webview);
            mywebview = FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.mywebiview);
            //This webviewchromeclient is very important
            mywebview.SetWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
            WebSettings webSettings = mywebview.Settings;
            //set javascript enabled for your webview
            webSettings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
            webSettings.JavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true;
             //set the object we defined above as the webviewclient for your webview
            mywebview.SetWebViewClient(new webViewClient());
         }
```